# how to update an element in an array searched by 'where' in 'postgresql'?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE tlps
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  telephone telephone[],
  CONSTRAINT tlps_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TYPE telephone AS
   (phone_code integer,
    number character varying(9)
)
```

I want to update the telephone 666666666 in telephone[] to 600000000

Comment: What's the definition of the `telephone` type? Is it a `domain` over `text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
insert into tlps values
(1, array['123456789', '666666666']);

update tlps 
set telephone = array_replace(telephone, '666666666', '600000000')
where id = 1;

select * from tlps;

 id |       telephone       
----+-----------------------
  1 | {123456789,600000000}
(1 row)
```

---

Case - the column `telephone` is of the composite type:

```
create type telephone as (phone_code integer, number character varying(9));

insert into tlps values
(1, array[(1,'123456789'), (2,'666666666')]::telephone[]);
```

Simple update `phone (2, '666666666')` to `phone (2, '600000000')` for a given `id`:

```
update tlps 
set telephone = array_replace(telephone, (2,'666666666')::telephone, (2,'600000000')::telephone)
where id = 1;
```

Find the phone number `'123456789'` and replace it with `'111222333'` (we do not know `phone_code` nor `id`):

```
with sel as (
    select id, u.phone_code
    from tlps, unnest(telephone) u
    where u.number = '123456789'
    )
update tlps t
set telephone = array_replace(telephone, (phone_code,'123456789')::telephone, (phone_code,'111222333')::telephone)
from sel s
where t.id = s.id;
```

Btw, I don't like the idea of storing phone numbers in such a complicated structure and don't know what it was invented for.

Comment: but if telephone is a type with phone_code and number?

Comment: Please, add the type definition to the question.

Comment: create type telephone as (phone_code integer, number character varying(9))